# How To Load Search Results On Floating Page

Tags: jquery, search

I want to create a Meta Search engine, on which I want to display search results on a floating or sliding page . I am a newbie that can u please tell me every thing which I need to make. Currently I had only this code.

```
<form method="get" action="http://www.google.com/search">
<input type="text" name="q" size="30" x-webkit-speech />
<input type="submit" value="Google Search" />
</form>
```

Comment: Try some code and ask us for suggestions or error fixing.

Comment: i want code to display results on floating page

Comment: if that's the case, show us a diagram in your mind

Comment: I want to create a php page on which a user can search and want to load a search result on a floating page so that user can view result without leaving website and need a close button on floating page so that user can get back to website page by clicking on that close button

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you need a PHP-AJAX search solution.

You can try **[Using Ajax to build a live search](http://www.finalwebsites.com/forums/topic/using-ajax-to-build-a-live-search)** (***[Here](http://www.finalwebsites.com/demos/jquery-forum-search/)*** is a demo).

Or you may pick one from **[14 jQuery Live Search Plugins](http://www.jquery4u.com/plugins/14-jquery-live-search-plugins/)**.

Hope this helps.

*Note:* Always do a little research YOURSELF and ask for help here in stackoverflow. You may also go through FAQ section. Also visit this page https://blog.stackoverflow.com/2010/10/asking-better-questions/

Comment: Ok i got little thing working and now i knw what really i want, i to show search results on a floating page like we get via Twitter Bootstrap.Js, cn u help me now to put search results on those floating page

Comment: buddy its the code i am asking for i had only search code i wanna code so that i can put results on a floating page with bootstrap means when users click on submit button result will be shown on floating page

Comment: so far i am here
<form method="get" action="http://www.google.com/search">
<input type="text" name="i" size="50" x-webkit-speech="x-webkit-speech" onwebkitspeechchange="this.form.submit();" />
</form>
when user speaks search will be done automatically and results are hosted on Google page but i want to load result on my floating page

Comment: First question: Do you have a server side script like PHP to fetch search results from database?

Comment: i dnt think script is needed as i want to put whole page in floating page not just result,for eg i had search box on abc.html page and search results are shown on xyz.html page, now i want to load whole xyz.html page in floating page not just search results

Comment: This is not a good practice. Even then you have to use some server side script in xyz.html to fetch results for your search. If you dont want a database, you may use it with simple text

Comment: it means the search results are attached in the web page itself or in an external file.

Comment: check this http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=L-J4R3R2h2s for Ajax + Jquery live search with NO database